# get creationdate from movie from photoalbum/UIimagepickercontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I get the creationdate of the movie that i got through the UIimagepickercontroller.
I got the following code but there's no info for the creationdate. I also tried file attributes but no luck.

```
NSURL *url = urlfromimagepicker;
NSDictionary *options = @{ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : @YES };
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:options];

NSArray *metadata = [asset commonMetadata];
for ( AVMetadataItem* item in metadata ) {
    NSString *key = [item commonKey];
    NSString *value = [item stringValue];
    NSLog(@"key = %@, value = %@", key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString* mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if(CFStringCompare((CFStringRef) mediaType,  kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
    {
        //Dismiss the media picker view
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        //Get the URL of the chosen content, then get the data from that URL
        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];

        //Gets the path for the URL, to allow it to be saved to the camera roll
        NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath))
        {
            ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

            //The key UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL allows you to get an ALAsset, which then allows you to get metadata (such as the date the media was created)
            [lib assetForURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                NSLog(@"created: %@", [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate]);
            } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

refer to this question:[How can I keep track of media created/chosen by UIImagePickerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474058/how-can-i-keep-track-of-media-created-chosen-by-uiimagepickercontroller)

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of this ugly alert asking for location permissions? I am not accessing a location, just a creationdate.

Answer (score 1):

`ALAsset` has `valueForProperty` property and it contains:

```
NSString *const ALAssetPropertyType;
NSString *const ALAssetPropertyLocation;
NSString *const ALAssetPropertyDuration;
NSString *const ALAssetPropertyOrientation;
NSString *const ALAssetPropertyDate;
NSString *const ALAssetPropertyRepresentations;
NSString *const ALAssetPropertyURLs;
NSString *const ALAssetPropertyAssetURL;
```

Use like this:

```
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultBlock = ^(ALAsset *myAsset){
     NSLog(@"created Date: %@",[myAsset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate]);
};
```